# How to use timezone with symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I am storing all times/datetimes in UTC timezone. I want to allow user to specify in which timezone he wants to view hours/dates - like in any other forum (phpbb, ipb and so on...)

What I did so far:

in `config.yml` I have set new doctrine types:

```
types:
    datetime: AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
    datetimetz: AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
    time: AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCTimeType
```

ex. `UTDDateTime`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types;

use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    /** @var DateTimeZone */
    private static $utc;
    /** @var DateTimeZone */
    private static $defaultTimeZone;

    /**
     * @param DateTime $dateTime
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($dateTime, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($dateTime instanceof DateTime) {
            $dateTime->setTimezone(self::getUtc());
        }
        return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($dateTime, $platform);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $dateTimeString
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @throws ConversionException
     *
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($dateTimeString, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (null === $dateTimeString || $dateTimeString instanceof DateTime) {
            return $dateTimeString;
        }
        $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($platform->getDateTimeFormatString(), $dateTimeString, self::getUtc());
        if (!$dateTime) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat(
                $dateTimeString,
                $this->getName(),
                $platform->getDateTimeFormatString()
            );
        }
        // set time zone
        $dateTime->setTimezone(self::getDefaultTimeZone());
        return $dateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeZone
     */
    private static function getUtc()
    {
        return self::$utc ? self::$utc : self::$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeZone
     */
    private static function getDefaultTimeZone()
    {
        return self::$defaultTimeZone
            ? self::$defaultTimeZone : self::$defaultTimeZone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
    }
}
```

I've made an `onKernelRequest` listener:

```
class TimezoneListener
{
    /**
     * @var AppSettingsService
     */
    private $settings;

    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(AppSettingsService $settings, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->settings = $settings->getAppSettings();
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set($this->settings->getDefaultTimeZone());
        $this->twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setTimezone($this->settings->getDefaultTimeZone());
    }
}
```

and configured my `php.ini` to `UTC`. And now comes the troubles:

Action `date_default_timezone_get()` from `UTCDateTimeType::getDefaultTimeZone()` runs before `onKernelRequest` set it to user's timezone so all dates are in server's `UTC` timezone. Any ideas how to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. You actually can simplify a bit:

In `config.yml` you only need to override `datetime`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            utcdatetime:
                name: datetime
                class: AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
```

In `UTCDateTimeType` you only need to ensure UTC datetimes are stored in the database:

```
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types;


use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

/**
 * Class UTCDateTimeType
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types
 */
class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTimeZone
     */
    private static $utc = null;

    /**
     * @param mixed            $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
            $value->setTimezone(self::getUtc());
        }

        return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed            $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return $this|mixed
     * @throws ConversionException
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (null === $value || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value;
        }

        $converted = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
            $platform->getDateTimeFormatString(),
            $value,
            self::$utc ? self::$utc : self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC')
        );

        if (!$converted) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat(
                $value,
                $this->getName(),
                $platform->getDateTimeFormatString()
            );
        }

        return $converted;
    }

    /** @return \DateTimeZone */
    private static function getUtc()
    {
        if (self::$utc === null) {
            self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
        }

        return self::$utc;
    }
}
```

Finally, your `onKernelRequest` listener doesn't need to set *server* timezone, just the Twig timezone:

```
class TimezoneListener
{
    /**
     * @var AppSettingsService
     */
    private $settings;

    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(AppSettingsService $settings, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->settings = $settings->getAppSettings();
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setTimezone($this->settings->getDefaultTimeZone());
    }
}
```